# Is there an SSLKEYLOGFILE equivalent for Safari to capture TLS session keys for debugging?

Tags: safari, ssl, wireshark

I'm trying to debug a Safari specific issue, but I can't see the data being passed in the TLS stream from a packet capture because I need the ephemeral keys to decrypt the session.  In Chrome or Firefox you can set the environment variable SSLKEYLOGFILE=/path/to/my-tls-session.keys and then use that file with wireshark to decrypt the session.

So, is there a way in Safari to have it record the TLS session keys?  If not, is there a way in Safari to capture the raw data stream that passes between it and the server?